# Managing SpriteKit Scenes Efficiently

Tags: macos, sprite-kit, skscene

Currently, I'm using an SKS file to set up my sprite locations via empty nodes or in some instances I am actually dragging and dropping the sprite into the scene editor. After having some loading issues, I was advised to preload all of the textures via a texture atlas. One issue that I came across before moving to this scheme was that my `didMoveToView` method was using more and more memory every time a scene loaded and reloaded. I have 3 scenes in my SpriteKit game: a main menu, level select and level scene. How should my scenes be managed? Should I create an instance of each and store them globally to avoid using too much memory? Currently, each scene is capable of initializing and calling `presentScene`. With my level scene there's a good amount of setup that needs to be done and when loading from the level selection scene I'm not sure if this should be recreated over and over again. I hope this is clear as to what I'm asking. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

SK does all of its memory management and caching behind the scenes. You really have no control over any of it. Short of your code having a memory leak or retain cycle somewhere, your app's memory usage will top out at a certain point.

If you want, you can manually 'nil out' all scene objects and `[self removeAllChildren];` in the `-(void)willMoveFromView:(SKView *)view` method.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I understand that memory is managed by arc, etc, but that wasn't my question. My question is more along the lines of scene management so that I don't incur memory leaks or other inefficiencies.

Comment: @02fentym - Without seeing your entire code, there's no way to tell you if you have a memory leak. That's not so much an issue of SKScene as it is of proper coding. If you think you have a memory leak somewhere, run Instruments and look for a leak.